# How to check/use md5 hash to a request stream in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just directly pipe the request stream to the gridfs write stream and it directly stored in the mongo databse using the mongo gridfs and this how it looks on the databse with the md5 hash and etc. Now I want to store duplicates to the database so my idea is to compare the md5 of the already added data in the databse to the new data from the request stream , Now how do i use md5 hash to the request stream so that i can compare it to the existing ?

## Code on downloading the file ang getting the stream

```
var download = function (url, dest, filename callback) {

   const file = filename
    const fileStorage = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: file});

    request.get(url)
        .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
        .pipe(fileStorage)
        .on('close', callback);

};

final_list.forEach(function (str) {
    var filename = str.split('/').pop();

    console.log('Downloading ' + filename);

    download(str, filename, function () { console.log('Finished Downloading' + "" + filename) });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try just creating an [`index`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/index.html) on the automatically generated [`md5`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#files.md5) field of your `GridFS` storage. That way it would reject duplicates automatically.

Comment: how do we create index ? not seem clear to me

Comment: Something like: `db.fs.files.createIndex( { md5: 1 } );`

Comment: that is after request.get(url)
        .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
        .pipe(fileStorage)
        .on('close', callback);

Comment: can you ellaborate ?

Comment: You would have to do it before doing anything else

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: where do creat this one db.fs.files.createIndex( { md5: 1 } ); ?