# How to create an index on the automatically generated md5 field of your GridFS storage. That way it would reject duplicates automatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

How can we create an index on the automatically generated md5 field of your GridFS storage. That way it would reject duplicates automatically.e. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The unique parameter while creating index should solve this.

```
db.col.createIndex( 'md5sumkeyname', { unique: true } )
```

refer:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232152/how-to-check-use-md5-hash-to-a-request-stream-in-node-js/58233044?noredirect=1#comment102897341_58233044

Comment: can you please check the link ?

Comment: my issue is connected on that stack question

Comment: sure, checking now

Comment: now where i do put this one db.col.createIndex( 'md5sumkeyname', { unique: true } )

Comment: indexing will not solve this problem, mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232152/how-to-check-use-md5-hash-to-a-request-stream-in-node-js/

Comment: so what would your adivice solution sir ?

Comment: you can use `db.fs.files.count('md5': md5SumFromTheCurrentFile)` to check if it is duplicate after writing to gridfs.

Comment: how do i get the md5SumFromTheCurrentFile ?

Comment: from my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232152/how-to-check-use-md5-hash-to-a-request-stream-in-node-js/58233044?noredirect=1#comment102897341_58233044

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200640/discussion-between-mr-mark-tawin-and-at07).